# How to redirect URL with %?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I made a mistake by accidentally included a white space in one of my urls and it was indexed by google. Does anyone know how I can 301 redirect urls with an empty space? I've tried the following but doesn't seem to be working

```
RewriteRule ^white-space%20-here(.*)$ http://abc.com/no-white-space-here$1 [R=301]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against the whitespace, and not the URL encoded `%20`. The URL gets decoded before being sent through the rewrite engine.

```
RewriteRule ^white-space\ -here(.*)$ http://abc.com/no-white-space-here$1 [R=301]
```